# Empty constructor and value passing problem

Tags: c++, constructor

When I create a class A object with a reference to class C, class B gives the error of: 
Error C2512 'A': no appropriate default constructor available

**Class A**

```
class A
    {
    public:

    C* cPointer;

    A(C* arg)
    {

        cPointer = arg;
    }

};
```

**Class B**

```
class B:
    public A
{

public:
    B()
    {

    }
};
```

If I add an empty constructor to class A it doesn't give errors but when I try to access cPointer it returns an empty address of 0000000000;

```
    A() 
    {   

    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

**Edit:** example

```
int main()
{

    C cObject;
    A a(&cObject);   

return 0;
}
```

> Result: Severity Code Description Project File Line   Suppression State
>   Error C2512   'A': no appropriate default constructor available

As I mentioned before if I put empty constructor to A it works but i cant use cPointer because it set to 0.
in class B:

```
cout << "Poniter: " << cPointer << endl;
```

result:

Pointer: 0000000000000000

> **Okay here is the actual code:**

**Skill.h** (class C in example)

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Unit.h"
using namespace std;


class Skill
{

public:
    Unit* unitPtr;


    Skill()
    {

    }
    Skill(Unit* unit) 
    {
        unitPtr = unit;
    }

    void SetUnit(Unit* unit)
    {
        unitPtr = unit;
    }

    vector <Skill *> attacks;
    vector <Skill *> utilities;
    vector <Skill *> movement;


};
```

**Unit.h** (class A in example)

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 
using namespace std;

class Skill;

class Unit
{
public:

    Skill* skillPtr;

    Unit(Skill* skill)
    {
        skillPtr = skill;   
    }

    void Setup();      
    string name;

    vector <Unit* > heroes;
    vector <Unit* > monsters;       

};
```

**Hero.h** (class B in example)

```
#pragma once
#include "Unit.h"


class Hero :
    public Unit
{

public:
    Hero() : Unit(skillPtr)
    {    
        cout << "Pointer: " <<  skillPtr << endl;
    }

};
```

**Main**

```
int main()
{

    Skill skill;
    Unit unit(&skill);   
    skill.SetUnit(&unit);
    unit.Setup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: In your `Hero.h`, what is `skillPtr` in the line: `Hero() : Unit(skillPtr)`? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: The default `Skill::Skill()` constructor is not initializing `unitPtr`.

Comment: skillPtr is Defined in the Unit.h, what I want is to access skillPtr from Hero.h. @scohe001 how can I initialize it before Hero use skillPtr?

Comment: `Hero` is inheriting `skillPtr` from the `Unit` class, **which hasn't been intiialized yet** when `Hero` is trying to pass `skillPtr` to the `Unit` constructor.  You have a circular reference that you need to break, since `Hero` does not have access to a valid `Skill` to initialize `Unit` with. Also, your `main()` doesn't show how you are trying to use `Hero`. Also, you might consider calling `Skill.SetUnit(this)` in the `Unit` constructor.

Comment: Ahh good call @Remy. So there's your problem, Utkan. `skillPtr` hasn't been initialized yet and you're using its value to call the `Unit` constructor to....initialize `skillPtr`. Do you see the issue? You probably wanted `Hero(Skill *ptr): Unit(ptr) { }` so that you can pass in a skill pointer to `Hero` to initialize with

Comment: @scohe001 Okay I understand to problem bu I didn't completely grasp the solution, so it is not possible to directly use skillPtr from Hero.h? If so how can i pass the pointer to Hero.h so i can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class B: public A {
    B() { }
}
```

When a child class's constructor is called, it first initializes its parent portion by calling a parent constructor. Since you didn't specify one here, the `B` constructor is trying to call the default `A` constructor, but one doesn't exist!

To call the constructor you made explicitly, you can do:

```
class B: public A {
    B(): A(Some_C_Pointer) { }
}
```

Comment: Now it doesn't give errors and I believe it is working but pointer still returns 0000000000. What can be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Or give `B()` a `C*` parameter, and then `B()` can pass that as-is to `A()`, eg: `B(C* arg): A(arg) { }`

Comment: @UtkanSüzmetaş You are clearly not initializing the pointer correctly, even with the suggestions you have been given. You need to initialize the pointer to point at *some* valid `C` object. Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] showing everything you are actually doing. For instance, how are you actually using `B`? We can't see that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau okay I added the actual code, there are child classes of Hero and Monster too but I don't think they are important in our case, I also deleted variable like "int health;" since they are unrelated.